# DNS resolution fails in Kubernetes POD running on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubeadm, coredns

I recently created a kubernetes cluster of one master and one slave (2 laptops) running Ubuntu 18.04 using Kubeadm and flannel for the network. I was able to deploy 2 microservices as 2 pods and created 2 services for either of them. I was able to call both API of both services using the node IP and the service port. But the pods were unable to communicate with each other using the service domain name.
Then I followed the  [debugging DNS issue page in official kubernetes website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).

On running `kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default` in the terminal
I keep getting

> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached. command terminated with exit code 1

All the rest of the steps in the above mentioned page works as expected. Towards the end, there is mention about the problem with resolv.conf in ubuntu and how to mitigate that. But I'm lost there and don't know how to implement that. Has anyone come accross this issue ? Can you help me fix it ?

Comment: core dns pods are running? what pod cidr you gave in kubeadm?

Comment: Yes they are running.

kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns 
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-6955765f44-crz59   1/1     Running   0          20m
coredns-6955765f44-gf4wq   1/1     Running   0          20m

Comment: as for pod cidr i gave 10.244.0.0/16

Comment: all pods are running in kube-system namespace? Do you have firewalld disabled?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes, i didn't specify any explicit namespace and also when i run  
`kubectl exec dnsutils cat /etc/resolv.conf`.  This is the result....  nameserver 10.96.0.10 
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5.  ................ My firewall is enabled

Comment: The pods are running on the default namespace

Comment: logs from flannel pod and CoreDNS pod

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Sorry for the delayed response. I did a fresh install on CentOS 8 and switched to weave net. I find the service using nsutils on the dnsutils pod but I'm still unable to curl a service using its name.

Comment: Ok, so turns out I wasn't using the fully qualified name of the service. Once i used the fully qualified name of the service it started working

Comment: I am facing the same issue with minikube and ubuntu 18.04. I am using service name to access it. Services is deployed to default namespace with NodePort enabled. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing a service from different namespace then you need to add the namespace where the service is `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` and if you are accessing it from same namespace then you can use `my-svc.svc.cluster.local` without any need to mention namespace.